# How does one implement expanding card animation/transition using react navigation (react-native)?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

What I want to achieve is an effect similar to [react-native-card-modal](https://github.com/ggomaeng/react-native-card-modal)
But I also want to change the route. The react native card modal uses the same component in which you have grow() and shrink() functions. The problem and the reason I want to avoid this way of implementing this is that I will have two levels of going inside the card and I will also have deep linking and I need to use a good navigation like [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) for that.

I will also need to go back. Looking for an elegant solution but feel free to share any tutorials to related transitions. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hey Vasil, did you manage to implement this? I'm looking to do something similar with a FlatList. Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this with a custom [transitioner](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/transitioner.html) in react-navigation.
[This blog post series](http://www.reactnativediary.com/2016/12/20/navigation-experimental-custom-transition-1.html) has a great detailed explanation, with a few examples.

**Edit: July 2022**

The Transitioner has been removed in the latest react-navigation in favor of using Animated configurations directly in the navigator options under a property called `cardStyleInterpolator`.

Stolen shamelessly from the docs - to create a fade transition you would create an interpolator:

```
const forFade = ({ current }) => ({
  cardStyle: {
    opacity: current.progress,
  },
});
```

And then use it in the navigator's properties:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Profile"
  component={Profile}
  options={{ cardStyleInterpolator: forFade }}
/>
```

For more examples see [the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animations).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!

Comment: @Kraylog sorry to bother you, but can you update the answer since React Navigation Transitioner is no longer supported in the newest version of React 6.x

Comment: Thanks Kraylog! It worked great combining { progress } property and Animated package!